# Date time picker : Reset

Tags: html, jquery-ui, datepicker, bootstrap-4, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I am using a [package](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker). Specifically [ThIS](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#view-mode).

Everything works fine, I clicks on the date picker, I selects year, Then month and then date, And the picker closes.

But when it closes and i click on it again, Only the last day calendar shows, Meaning it doesn't starts over again from year.

What i want is that, It should starts over again from year to month to day.

**Here is the [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s4dc2fbj/60/)**

Here is my code :

```
<div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker9'>
    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Js :

```
$(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker9').datetimepicker({
        viewMode: 'years'
    });
});
```

Comment: You need to clear the instance of the function from your element and re-run it.  or you have the clear method https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#showclear

Comment: @AlexanderSashaShcherbakov its not working with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reset the [`viewMode`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#viewmode) using [`dp.hide`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Events/#dphide) event and a `setTimeout`

```js
let $datePicker = $('#myDatepicker').datetimepicker({
  useCurrent: false,
  viewMode: 'years'
});

$datePicker.on('dp.hide', function(event) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $datePicker.data('DateTimePicker').viewMode('years');
  }, 1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/25c11d79/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<br/>
<!--Space for the fiddle-->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class='input-group date' id='myDatepicker'>
          <input type='text' class="form-control" />
          <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```